# Disable one button if it has been executed

Tags: android, button, popup, buttonclick

I have written some lines to popup a form by pressing a `Button`. Now im trying to deactivate the `Button` if its pressed so it will not open again.

Here is tha main activity File:

```
package com.javacodegeeks.android.fragmentstest;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.PopupWindow;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;


@SuppressLint("InflateParams")
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {

    ImageView mButton1;
    Context contex;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      mButton1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.button1);
      mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

           @SuppressWarnings("null")
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater 
             = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext()
              .getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);  
            View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupform, null);  
                     final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                       popupView, 
                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                             LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);  

                    Button btnbutton1 = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.login);

                    btnbutton1.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){

             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              popupWindow.dismiss();
             }});


                   popupWindow.showAsDropDown(btnbutton1, 50, 250);

            }
      });

    }
```

We make a note here that this is part of the code thus there is more after this. But I'm stuck on this part!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just disable it...

```
mButton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

       @SuppressWarnings("null")
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        mButton1.setEnabled(false);
        // your other code
```

You could also just set it on the `View` if you use this code in the future for other `Views`

```
public void onClick(View arg0) {  
        arg0.setEnabled(false);
        // your other code
```

If you want to re-enable it then simply override `onDismiss()` of your popup and enable the `Button`

```
@Override
public void onDismiss() {
    mButton1 .setEnabled(true);
```

[Docs for setEnabled()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setEnabled(boolean))

[Docs for onDismiss()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.OnDismissListener.html)

I would also consider changing the param to something meaningful. Instead of the default `arg0` use something like `v` or `view`.

```
 View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popupform, null);  
                 final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                   popupView, 
                   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
                         LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupWindow.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.DismissListener
{
    @Overide
    public void onDismiss() {
         mButton1 .setEnabled(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: That's why I added the bit about overriding onDismiss (). That will be called when you close the pop up

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do `button.setEnabled(false);` to disable the button. you should try this approach. make a boolean for when the form is opened and if it is true you disable the button.